AWS CDK test fails: "Template has 0 resources with type AWS::EC2::VPC" even though it is defined in stack
In my CDK test code I have the following test defined (unique identifiers have been obfuscated):
test('VPC Created', () => {
    template.hasResourceProperties('AWS::EC2::VPC', {
        VpcId: 'vpc_<unique_id>',
        availabilityZones: ['<zone_1>', '<zone_2>'],
        privateSubnetIds: [
            'subnet-<unique_id>',
            'subnet-<unique_id>'
        ]
    });
})

In my CDK stack code, the VPC is defined as follows:
const defaultVpc = ec2.Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, 'lambdaVpc', {
    vpcId: 'vpc_<unique_id>',
    availabilityZones: ['<zone_1>', '<zone_2>'],
    privateSubnetIds: [
        'subnet-<unique_id>',
        'subnet-<unique_id>'
    ]
});

And yet, when I run npm test, I get the following error:
 FAIL  test/infrastructure.test.ts (22.031 s)
  × VPC Created (47 ms)
  √ Lambda Function Created (1 ms)
  √ API Gateway Created

  ● VPC Created

    Template has 0 resources with type AWS::EC2::VPC.
    No matches found

       9 |
      10 | test('VPC Created', () => {
    > 11 |     template.hasResourceProperties('AWS::EC2::VPC', {
         |              ^
      12 |         VpcId: 'vpc-<unique_id>',
      13 |         availabilityZones: ['<zone_1>', '<zone_2>'],
      14 |         privateSubnetIds: [

      at Template.hasResourceProperties (node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/assertions/lib/template.js:1:3101)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/infrastructure.test.ts:11:14)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        23.309 s, estimated 24 s
Ran all test suites.

Why am I getting this error, even though my resource clearly is defined in the template?  I have other resources in the template defined similarly (Lambda, API Gateway), and they are passing the tests.  Why does the VPC test fail?

The fromVpcAttributes method is used to import an existing VPC. Where is that VPC defined?

@lpizzinidev it's an existing VPC in my AWS account.  BTW, the actual deployment works fine.  If I deploy my app to AWS via my pipelines, the app deploys/runs successfully.  I've added this test "after the fact".

@lpizzinidev - ah, I think I see the problem.  Since fromVpcAttributes and fromLookup retrieve the resources from the AWS instance, I'm guessing they can't be used in CDK tests, since tests can only use resources that have been created in the CDK stack/template.

@CB_at_Sw Resources which are loaded with e.g., from*Attributes and fromLookup are not added as resources in the CloudFormation template and cannot be tested with hasResourceProperties and similar assertions. Those imported references will appear rather as raw values during synth or deploy actions. I would recommand either importing the VPC to CDK fully or refactoring your test by asserting the resources which are using the defaultVpc.

The comments left by @lpizzinidev and @christian-banfi answered my question.  Thanks!
